# How do I convert a float to a 16 bit signed integer fraction in C?

Tags: floating-point, data-conversion, short

I'm using a macro from a library supplied by NXP for their Arm M4F to convert from a float typed variable to a library data type called frac16_t and it doesn't work when the float value is less than -1.  The frac16_t is typedef'd as a signed short.

The macro code is:

#define FRAC16(x) ((frac16_t)((x) < 0.999969482421875 ? ((x) >= -1 ? (x)*0x8000 : 0x8000) : 0x7fff))

The intended behavior of this macro is to convert any float value between -1 and +1 to a 16 signed integer representing the range from -1 to (1 - 1/2^15) with 0x8000 as the -1 value and 0x7fff and the nearly 1 value.  If the float value is greater than (nearly) one the result saturates at 0x7fff and when the float is less than -1 the result is supposed to be 0x8000.

What actually happens is that for any input that's less than -1 the result is 0x7fff (i.e. nearly 1) and for any other value it works as advertised.

I did find that casting the 0x8000 constant to the frac16_t type makes the macro work correctly but I don't understand why the original library macro doesn't work.  Changing the constant to -32768 also works and both of those fixes result in the constant being coded as 32 bits long which requires that the value be loaded indirectly from somewhere in flash near the load instruction vs loading as a 16 bit literal that's part of the instruction.

Comment: *What actually happens is that for any input that's less than -1 the result is 0x7fff (i.e. nearly 1) and for any other value it works as advertised.*.. Isn't it only "advertised" to work for values between -1 and 1 as you stated earlier: *The intended behavior of this macro is to convert any float value between -1 and +1 to...*? Btw, as-is, it doesn't work for values > 1 either (as described). The macro assumes a denominator of 0x8000, and since it's limiting values to 16-bit signed numbers, the input values are limited to -1 to 1. Otherwise, the result would be more than 16 bits.

Comment: Do not think that 0x8000 is -32768.  It is 32768.

Comment: Lurker: FWIW, the "defined behavior" I posted includes results when the input is outside the -1 to +1 range (0x7fff for inputs greater than 1 and -0x8000 for less than -1) all of which fit inside a short int.  Behavior for -1 to +1 isn't the only requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> both of those fixes result in the constant being coded as 32 bits long which requires that the value be loaded indirectly from somewhere in flash

Not quite.  The hex constants are converted to `double` and later to `signed short`.

First with `test ? some_type_A : some_type_B`, the result is a common type.  In this case, `double`.

`(x)*0x8000` is a `double` (or `float`), then `: 0x8000` and then `: 0x7fff` also become the same floating point type.

`0x8000` becomes a 32768.0.  Assigning an out of range `double` to `signed short` is UB.
A common UB is out-of-range values take on the min/max limit.
In OP's case `double` 32768.0 became `signed short` 32767.

```
#define FRAC16(x) \\
    ((frac16_t)((x) < 0.999969482421875 ? ((x) >= -1 ? (x)*0x8000 : 0x8000) : 0x7fff))
//                                                                  ^^^^^^    
//                                                                  32768.0
```

Instead of assigning 32768.0 to a `signed short` and invoking *undefined behavior*, assign -32768.0 for defined behavior.

```
#define FRAC16(x)
    ((frac16_t)((x) < 0.999969482421875 ? ((x) >= -1 ? (x)*0x8000 : -32768 : 0x7fff))
//                                                                  ^^^^^^^
//                                                                  -32768.0
```

---

If one wants to code with `SHRT_MIN`, do not use `0x8000`, use `SHRT_MIN` or `(-0x7fff - 1)`.

Comment: It looks like the crux of the matter is that 0x8000 is treated by the compiler as +32768 plus the lack of a single Thumb instruction that can load a negative 16 bit value into a 32 bit register.